# mongodb document structure - limitation and performance advice needed

Tags: performance, mongodb

I'm designing the structure of a mongodb document, which contains an array of objects as one of the attributes:

> {
>     _id : xxx,
>     someObjectAttribute : { ... },
>     someArrayAttribute : [ { timeStamp: yyy, value: zzz } , ... ]
>   }

It's envisioned that 'someArrayAttribute' above may need to hold millions of elements, each with the same structure of {timeStamp, value}, and on which aggregations and filtrations will be done (e.g., sum of values over a time period).

I would like to get advice on:

- Whether the above structure is plausible for the said volume of elements, and if there
  are obvious design weaknesses for performance
- The maximum number of elements 'someArrayAttribute' can possibly contain
- Whether a better structure than above can make use of mongodb's built-in aggregations

Thanks in advance, I'd be glad to clarify anything.

Answer (score 1):

> that 'someArrayAttribute' above may need to hold millions of elements,

Nope, won't work.

A document is limited by 16MB of space. Millions will not fit into that so with just considering that:

> Whether the above structure is plausible for the said volume of elements, and if there are obvious design weaknesses for performance

No

> The maximum number of elements 'someArrayAttribute' can possibly contain

Much less, more like 12,000 with very small objects but even then you will get performance problems working on such a large array unless you split it down into chunks within the document.

> Whether a better structure than above can make use of mongodb's built-in aggregations

The only real structure you can have is the parent document in one collection and the `someArrayAttribute` split out into a separate collection.

You could, I suppose, house chunks of `someArrayAttribute` within documents within another collection or even the same collection but that sounds tedious and precariously complicated.